# Expansion of "\coord" macro in TikZ "let" command

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calc

Please consider this code:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\coord(#1){coordinate(#1)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw](A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[draw](B) at (3,3) {B};
    % this works
    \draw let \p1=(A), \p2=(B) in (A) -- (\x1, \y2) coordinate(C);
    % this fails
    % \draw let \p1=(A), \p2=(B) in (A) -- (\x1, \y2) \coord(C);
    \node [right] at (C) {\pgfversion};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The commented line fails  --- it seems that in the `let` path the `\coord` macro is not expanded. Is this expected?

PD. I use this because I use the following code:

```latex
\def\normcoord(#1){coordinate(#1)}
\def\showcoord(#1){node[circle, red, draw, inner sep=1pt,pin={[red, overlay, inner sep=0.5pt, font=\tiny, pin distance=0.1cm, pin edge={red, overlay,}]45:#1}](#1){}}
\let\coord=\showcoord
```

to switch between "marked" and "unmarked" nodes while I build drawings.

Comment: \coord is actually a command that gets defined similarly to \n and \p. So rename your macro. An only on my cell phone now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were just unlucky since you chose to call your macro `\coord`, which already has a meaning. It allows us to recall how a coordinate was defined. So if you use, say, `\mycoord` instead of `\coord`, your code works as expected. I also added something that shows what `\coord` does. You may think of it as a cousin of `\n`, `\p`, `\x` and `\y`, which also have special meanings in the `let ... in` syntax. While `\p` allows you to "set" the point, `\x` and `\y` yield their screen coordinates and `\coord` the string by which the coordinate was defined. In more detail, the available macros are (taken from `tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex`)

```
  \let\p=\tikz@cc@dop%
  \let\x=\tikz@cc@dox%
  \let\y=\tikz@cc@doy%
  \let\n=\tikz@cc@don%
  \let\rawx=\tikz@cc@dotempx%
  \let\rawy=\tikz@cc@dotempy%
  \let\rawz=\tikz@cc@dotempz%
  \let\coord=\tikz@cc@docoord%
```

As of now, it also contains `\rawx`, `\rawy` and `\rawz`, which are the components of the coordinates that were used to define the coordinate.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\mycoord(#1){coordinate(#1)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw](A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[draw](B) at (3,3) {B};
    % this works
    \draw let \p1=(A), \p2=(B) in (A) -- (\x1, \y2) coordinate(C);
    % this also works
    \draw let \p1=(A), \p2=(B) in (A) -- (\x1, \y2) \mycoord(C);
    \node [right] at (C) {\pgfversion};
    \path let \p{A}=(A),\p{B}=(B),\p{C}=(C) in
    (0,3) node[anchor=south west,align=left] {Let us show how\\ 
    we were defined:\\$A=\coord{A}$\\
    $B=\coord{B}$\\ $C=\coord{C}$\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me also mention that `\coord`, or related tools, is an indispensable tool in 3D computations since the screen coordinates are always just projections, i.e. among other things you lose the third component. To which extent this will be used in a meaningful way depends on future developments of Ti*k*Z. The main problem is that, as of now, it does not get recorded in which frame the coordinate got defined.

Since Henri Menke asked me to, I mention that he decided to remove `\coord`, `\rawx`, `\rawy` and `\rawz`. IMHO this move is unnecessary and breaks working codes. But this very issue may not appear in the future.

However, this is not at all a special situation. Rather, for instance I usually call loop variables `\X`, `\Y` and so on, simply because the calc syntax uses and redefines `\x` and `\y` (and `\x` is also the default plot parameter). That is, `\x` and `\y` also get overwritten without warning, and users usually learn to avoid collisions by naming their macros differently. Sometimes even very basic commands (e.g. `\xi`) get overwritten, but as long as one knows that this happens one can always find a way to solve this. There is only a finite number of macro names. Every `\foreach` loop overwrites its loop variables without warning.

Comment: You might want to mention that the user command `\coord` will be removed in PGF 3.1.5.

Comment: Yay! I used `\coord` all around my `circuitikz` manual :-(. Bad on my side, I should had used `\newcommand` (but well, in my defense, the idea was to make the code `context` compatible). I was thinking in a big search and replace, but @HenriMenke says it will disappear in next release...

Comment: @HenriMenke I mention that I strongly disagree with that move. I still hope that you change your mind. There is absolutely no reason for removing it other than being mean to others. Sorry to say that so clearly.

Comment: @Rmano To be clear, I do not think it is a reasonable decision to remove `\coord`. It has already been used and there are no issues per se with that command. (There are related issues with the syntax that you need to make Ti*k*Z remember how it defined the coordinates, but this does not mean that `\coord` does not work.) There are quite a few codes that rely on `\coord` in the answers, and removing it will hurt all those who are using these codes.

Comment: @HenriMenke I have no strong opinion about that. It's not so difficult to use `\mcoord` or whatever... That kind of things happens when the name space is shared like in TeX.

Answer (score 3):

In PGF 3.1.4 I made the mistake to introduce new user-level commands without documenting them.  These commands are defined inside the `let` operation and overwrite a possible global definition unconditionally.  These local macros are

```
\rawx
\rawy
\rawz
\coord
```

It was meant as an experiment, which has been proven to have failed in many instances now.  Therefore in the upcoming PGF 3.1.5 release I am going to remove these commands again.  You can restore the correct behaviour of the `let` operation by overriding the definition in your preamble after loading the `calc` library.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@let@command et{%
  \let\p=\tikz@cc@dop%
  \let\x=\tikz@cc@dox%
  \let\y=\tikz@cc@doy%
  \let\n=\tikz@cc@don%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar i{\tikz@cc@stop@let}{\tikz@cc@handle@line}%
}%
\makeatother

\def\coord(#1){coordinate(#1)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw](A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[draw](B) at (3,3) {B};
    % this works
    \draw let \p1=(A), \p2=(B) in (A) -- (\x1, \y2) coordinate(C);
    % this fails
    \draw let \p1=(A), \p2=(B) in (A) -- (\x1, \y2) \coord(C);
    \node [right] at (C) {\pgfversion};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You were once advertising those as nice achievements. What precisely are the failed experiments you are mentioning? This is all a bit off IMHO. Will you invalidate other answers by just deciding that you change the syntax? Maybe one day others will do that with packages that you are using, and you will learn how that feels.

Comment: The argument that user-defined macros get overwritten is also not a real argument. How many `\def`s are were in `tikz.code.tex`, and how many `\newcommand`s? Basically all Ti*k*Z macros overwrite user-defined commands, simply because they are defined via `\def`, and we both know why that is.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat There is nothing preventing you from releasing your own version of a `calc` library that has all the features you want.

Comment: Not if someone changes core functions in TI*k*Z at will and single-handedly. As I said, maybe others will learn from this example, and one day you will be the one whose code does not work anymore because someone decided to make substantial changes. And as you know, I am not personally affected, I am speaking up for those who will only learn about this once it is too late.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat As a ConTeXt user on latest beta I can just shrug at your comment.

Comment: I see. Because you have to suffer, others should suffer, too.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Not my problem that you choose to use undocumented interfaces.

Comment: This is not about me. This is about the question whether or not a single person can add or remove features because they just feel like it. Or more precisely, add features, advertise them, and remove them after others have used them. Or upload code by others on CTAN without notifying others, let alone ask, and then not even volunteering in removing the code. Or use the chat to tell others which answers they are to accept.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat If you don't want others to share your code, you should not [release it under GPL](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/blob/1d0ff2ef164b6b149dd89b3862606fad01865b8d/experiments/Marmot/3dtools/tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex#L3-L6).

Comment: I never *released* my code, sorry. And if a code is public, this does not mean that a random person can submit it to CTAN. Again, this is not about me. It is about how decisions about projects are made. I am a fan of democracy and thoughtful decisions, and of listening to arguments of others, and not so much of glancing at something, making a quick decision which cannot be challenged. If you want to remove something because some experiments have failed, don't you think that others deserve information on these experiments?

Comment: Actually adding another version of `calc` is a good idea. Not so much to be immune to changes of the Ti*k*Z ecosystem (which I still do not think are a good idea), but to use `fpu` for the coordinate computations.  This may be be slower but spare the user from `dimension too large` errors in cases where the intermediate results in a computation are large, but the final values well-behaved.